# how to get download link in python using beautifulsoup?

Tags: python-2.7

i want to get the download link. For example in http://www.brothersoft.com/windows/top-downloads/

so the expected result should be:

```
List of url:
 1. http://www.brothersoft.com/photoscape-64604.html
 2. http://www.brothersoft.com/orbit-downloader-54366.html
 3. ....
 4. ...
 till 100.
```

I have tried this code:

```
 import urllib
 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

 pageFile = urllib.urlopen("http://www.brothersoft.com/windows/top-downloads/")

 pageHtml = pageFile.read()

 pageFile.close()

 soup = BeautifulSoup("".join(pageHtml))

 sAll = soup.findAll("a")

 for i in range (0,100)
    for link in sAll:
      print i,link
```

But it give incorrect output.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, `BeautifulSoup("".join(pageHtml))` is not needed since pageHtml is already a string, so you can just use that directly like `BeautifulSoup(pageHtml)`.

`for i in range (0,100)`

If you're using Python 2 (which I think you do, since Python 3's urllib has no `urlopen`), you should use xrange(100) instead, it's a bit faster, also it's not needed to include the first zero if you're counting from zero, so xrange(100) will do just fine.

Also, you have a syntax error, no space between `range` and `(0,100)` and add a `:` directly after it.

Finally, your code will just print all the links 100 times, which is not what you need; if you only need the first 100 links you should use something like this :

`for i in xrange(100):
    print sAll[i]["href"]`

This basically makes a list from 0 to 100, and iterates over it, the current value is in `i`, then it uses that `i` as an index for retrieving data from the `sAll` array (obviously this will throw a KeyError exception if the sAll list is smaller than 100), and finally it prints the "href" attribute of that item, which is the link target.

If you wanted to also print the number, you could use `print i, sAll[i]["href"]` instead.

Comment: i got this error :   File "C:\Documents and Settings\Fairuz\Desktop\soup.py", line 13, in <module>
    print i, sAll[i]["href"]
  File "C:\Python27\lib\encodings\cp437.py", line 12, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,errors,encoding_map)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character u'\u2013' in position
 115: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: File "C:\Documents and Settings\Fairuz\Desktop\soup.py", line 13, in <module>
    print i, sAll[i]["href"]
  File "C:\Python27\lib\encodings\cp437.py", line 12, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,errors,encoding_map)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character u'\u2013' in position
 115: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: The same code runs fine on my Linux desktop, that issue is specific to your Windows XP desktop... You can try `print i, sAll[i]["href"].encode('utf-8', 'replace')` which should get around the errors but some characters won't be displayed properly - that's a limitation of your Windows terminal/command prompt.

Comment: it works..but i need output like: 
List of url:
 1. http://www.brothersoft.com/photoscape-64604.html
 2. http://www.brothersoft.com/orbit-downloader-54366.html

Comment: Well, it looks like there are both relative links (/some/where) and absolute links (http://someserver/some/where) so you should check that, also this basic code also gets all the social media links like the Facebook share button so it's not perfect either, you need to also prevent that. And finally, BrotherSoft is probably the worst place to go if you need software, you'll mostly find adware and various toolbars, i suggest you move on to a different site.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35879/discussion-between-wan-mohd-payed-and-andre-daniel)